# Correcting temperature data for seasonality given the outside air temp

Tags: seasonality, adjustment

I'm wondering how I could use historical outside air temperature to correct/adjust temp sensor readings I have.

I know how to adjust for seasonality in accounting/forecasting where I would use my historical sensor data to derive the seasonal impact, but in this case I don't need to calculate the perceived seasonal change as the exact temperature for each day is known.

It feels too simple to just do a translation of the data e.g. take the sensor temps and subtract the outside air temp from them to smooth the data (and adding back the mean as a constant such that the numbers look realistic). The distribution passes the eye test, but i'm not sure its statistically valid.

I also normalized the outside air temp using `(t - u)/sd` and then tried multiplying the sensor temps by each normalized value. Again this seems to smooth out the data in a similar manner.

Are either of these ways the right way to do it or is there a better way to use the information I have to adjust my readings?

Comment: This will depend on what you want to use the adjusted temperatures for. If you simply subtract the outside temperatures, then your adjusted data are the difference between the measured and the outside temperatures, and that may be exactly what you want. Can you clarify what you want to do with the adjusted data?

Comment: I have a cooling unit and the sensor temps measure the outlet temp. If the temp is higher this may be an indication that the cooler's performance has started to deteriorate, however the air coming in and being cooled is obviously affected by the season. I dont my data to imply a cooler isnt working very well just because it was a hotter day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to work with multiple anomality detectors.

1. Use the time series of reported temperatures. After all, this is what you are presumably interested in: if the cooler gets too warm for whatever you are trying to cool, then it won't help you much if this is because it was too hot outside. The contents will still be spoiled.
2. In addition, use the time series of differences between the reported and the outside temperatures to account for the influence of the surrounding temperatures.

In each case, look at statistical control charts. The idea is to fit a time series model to the history except for the last few data points, forecast this out into the holdout sample and compare forecast to actuals. You will need to tweak the conditions under which you raise an alert. Maybe you will track the last five readings (so we get ten data points, because we have two time series) and raise an alert if nine of these are above the mean forecast. Or if the reported temperature has been above the 80th prediction quantile (see prediction intervals) for five data points *and* the outside temperature has been below the historical mean, or some similar combination of conditions.

In any case, it would be good to use a seasonal model, to account for temperature differences between summer and winter. Seasonal [exponential smoothing](https://www.otexts.org/fpp2/ch-expsmooth.html) would be a good thing, best in a state space framework to give you prediction intervals.

Comment: I can use a mixture model and or use bayes for anomaly detection. I also have two sensors so monitoring the delta between them along with the air temp should help identify when one sensor is acting strange. Thanks